# How can I use router navigate in ionic4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I’m migrating source code from ionic3 to ionic4.
I want to set the first page as the login.page in my new ionic4 app.
So, I wrote router.navigateByUrl in my app.component.ts.
But It's not working.
I wrote console.log in the constructor and ionViewWillEnter of login.page.ts, 
but it does not seem to be called.
Please help me.

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    providers: [CustomNativeStorage, PointsService]
})

export class MyApp {
.
.
this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
.
```

**app.componet.html**

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule)},
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then( m => m.TabsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then( m => m.LoginPageModule)
  },
```

**login.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { LoginPageRoutingModule } from './login-routing.module';
import { LoginPage } from './login.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    LoginPageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [LoginPage]
})
export class LoginPageModule {}
```

**login-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginPage } from './login.page';
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginPage
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class LoginPageRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to login in `app-routing.module.ts` : 
`{ path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' }`

Comment: It's not work.  I wrote console.log in the constructor and ionViewWillEnter of login.page.ts, but it does not seem to be called.

Comment: Can you give a try to replace "loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then( m => m.LoginPageModule)" with "loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule'" ?

Comment: I tried your suggestion. But login.page is not called.

Comment: I feels completely ignored about router.navigate.I don't know why.

Comment: When I change app-routing.module.ts's

`loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then( m => m.LoginPageModule)`
to
`component: LoginPage`

It works. But I don't know why.